# Python FastApi multi-threading race condition problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, fastapi, race-condition

This is the error that I get in console:

```
Exception in thread AnyIO worker thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
```

I use FastApi & Mariadb, the endpoint that I cought creating this issue is one that returns a video as `application/octet-stream` using fastapi's `FileResponse`, the more videos I created to test my app the slower the response gets + sometimes the request just stays on pending without response and I have to restart the server,
heres a summary of the code:

```
@router.get('/{id}') 
def get_my(request:Request,id:str,depends=Depends(auth.get_token_header)): 
    try:
        user = User(cur).getOne(request.session.get('user')['email'])
        if not user:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=500,detail={"error":'User Does not exist'})
        video =  Videos(cur).get_one(id)
        if video['user'] != user['id']:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Not found")
        return FileResponse(path=video['path'], media_type='application/octet-stream', filename=video['uuid']+ '.mp4')
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail={"error":str(e)})
```

```
class Videos:
    def __init__(self,cur):
        self.cur = cur
    
    
    def get_one(self,id):
        sql="""select id,user,path,uuid,created from user_videos where uuid = %s limit 1"""
        values=[(id)]
        self.cur.execute(sql,values)
        video = self.cur.fetchone()
        return video
```

I tried looking for an answer online but found nothing usefull, im not using asyncio and im not sure if I should, let me know what you think, for me this is some weird multi-threading race condition problem.